# Not all properties are mapped while querying Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm looking to integrate Azure CosmosDB into our project. The goal I've set for myself is to create an FAQ-section. I've created the table and also added three collections to it with some example data. However, when querying I can see that not all properties are begin mapped from the JSON and therefore my query gives no result.

My model classes look like this;

**BasisDocumentDBEntity**

```
//This is a base class with some common shared properties
public abstract class BasisDocumentDBEntity
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "AangemaaktDoor")]
    public string AangemaaktDoor { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "AangemaaktOp")]
    public DateTime AangemaaktOp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "GewijzigdOp")]
    public DateTime GewijzigdOp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "GewijzigdDoor")]
    public string GewijzigdDoor { get; set; }
}
```

**FAQGroup**

```
//I've came up with groups for FAQ. A group for example can be 'General' or 'Instruction video's'
public class FAQGroup : BasisDocumentDBEntity
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Name")]
    public string Naam { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Sections")]
    public List<FaqSection> Sections { get; set; }
}
```

**FaqSection**

```
//Each group can contain one or more sections. And each section can contain one or more questions.
public class FaqSection : BasisDocumentDBEntity
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "GroupId")]
    public string GroupId { get; set; }

    public FAQGroup Group { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Questions")]
    public List<FAQQuestion> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

**FAQQuestion**

```
//The actual question with the answer in it.
public class FAQQuestion : BasisDocumentDBEntity
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Question")]
    public string Question { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Answer")]
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

I know that CosmosDB isn't a relational databasetype. But if I understand [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data) correctly it should somewhat be possible.

My example data is stored lik this in the CosmosDB;

**Group:**

```
{
"id": "1",
"Name": "Group 1",
"Sections": [
    1,
    2,
    3
],
"AangemaaktDoor": "user",
"AangemaaktOp": "2018-07-17 08:46",
"GewijzigdDoor": "user",
"GewijzigdOp": "2018-07-17 08:46",
"_rid": "<snip>",
"_self": "<snip>",
"_etag": "<snip>",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1531818056
}
```

**Section:**

```
{
"id": "1",
"GroupId": "1",
"Title": "Common",
"Questions": [
    1,
    2,
    3
],
"AangemaaktDoor": "user",
"AangemaaktOp": "2018-07-17 08:46",
"GewijzigdDoor": "user",
"GewijzigdOp": "2018-07-17 08:46",
"_rid": "<snip>",
"_self": "<snip>",
"_etag": "<snip>",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1531810510
}
```

**Question:**

```
{
"id": "1",
"Question": "My First Question is?",
"Answer": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ultrices convallis sapien, sed vestibulum nisl mollis eget. Sed feugiat aliquet orci. Sed pretium feugiat enim, nec lacinia lacus eleifend et. Morbi vitae risus cursus sapien sodales ullamcorper id ut eros. Cras semper ipsum at congue tempus. Fusce hendrerit lorem lorem, non fermentum purus vehicula vel. Nulla aliquam lorem turpis, venenatis hendrerit ligula efficitur eget. Curabitur et erat quis diam interdum vestibulum. Proin congue feugiat dui, a feugiat nisi bibendum eget. Etiam congue orci eget magna efficitur semper. Sed mattis posuere ex, ut venenatis augue condimentum ac. Etiam tincidunt est odio, vitae interdum nibh mollis a. Aliquam id hendrerit dui, et bibendum justo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.",
"AangemaaktDoor": "user",
"AangemaaktOp": "2018-07-17 08:46",
"GewijzigdDoor": "user",
"GewijzigdOp": "2018-07-17 08:46",
"_rid": "<snip>",
"_self": "<snip>",
"_etag": "<snip>",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1531810570
}
```

I'm using [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-dotnet) on the microsoft documentation as a reference. But I can't figure out why some properties are filled and some are not. This is what I'm getting back from my repository;

[image]

The GroupId- and Title-field both don't containt any data. And I can't get my head around it. Feels like something obvious. Anybody any idea?

**UPDATE**

```
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> 
predicate)
            {
            if (!_isInitialized) throw new InvalidOperationException("Repository must be initialized first!");

            //Query with filter >> returns nothing
            IDocumentQuery<T> query = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseId, _collectionId),
                new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true })
                .Where(predicate)
                .AsDocumentQuery();

            //Query without filter >> returns list with single section but empty 'GroupId' and empty 'Title'
            var xquery = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseId, _collectionId),
            new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true })
            .ToList();

            List<T> results = new List<T>();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
            }

            return results;
        }
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
    public async Task<SectionDTO> GetFAQOverzicht(EFaqGroup faqGroup)
    {
        var faqSection = new SectionDTO();

        var groupId = ((int) faqGroup).ToString();
        var section = await DocumentDBRepository<FaqSection>.GetItemsAsync(faq => faq.GroupId == groupId);

        return faqSection;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're pulling through the data from the correct collection?

Comment: How are you querying for this data? Are you joining in CosmosDB SQL? Are you doing multiple queries to get the objects?

Comment: @NickChapsas, I'll update the question with the query shortly. I understand I need to do joins or multiple queries to get things done. But the issue at the moment is that two mandatory fields 'GroupId' and 'Title' doesn't contain any data. Even though in my test set they're filled.

Answer (score 1):

CosmosDB is not a relational database as you already said. The CosmosDB SDK you are using isn't an ORM. It's just a wrapper around the CosmosDB API.

That means that unless you use joins or do multiple queries to do the retrieval you can't just get the other objects from their respective collections.

Just because you have a GroupId property that has a number in it doesn't mean that the Section collection has any sort of relationship with the Group collection. It isn't Entity Framework. To CosmosDB and to the SDK they are just two separate collections that have no relationships between them.

In order to do what you want you either need to do multiple queries to populate the object you're retrieving (one for each sub objects which is not recommended) or join to the other two tables with CosmosDB SQL and map the retrieved results to yourobject.

Comment: I understand this and it completely makes sense. But my issue at the moment is that the fields I want to use to join doesn't contain any data. The fields 'GroupId' and 'Title' are empty and I don't understand why.

Comment: Can you show me the `GetItemsAsync` method call. I suspect that you query for the `Question` or the `Group` object which is the only one without those two properties

Comment: I've updated the question again with the code. I understand your point, but at the moment I'm querying for the Section.

Comment: But how are you limiting your results for Section? Is this Repository talking to a collection that contains just `Section` objects, cuz to me it looks like it's not.

Comment: the repository take a generic parameter called 'T', T in this case is the FAQSection class and that is how it should be limiting the repository to just this type

Comment: @Rob But where in the code are you limiting that? Just passing the T parameter to the `CreateDocumentQuery` method won't limit it to those objects. The SDK doesn't have this logic in it. It's a mapping instruction. You basically tell it to return any `Document` it has and try to map it on the `T` parameter. CosmosDB is type agnostic so unless you explicitly tell it what you want it will return everything.

Comment: @Rob I actually have to code this feature in the ORM i wrote, [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut#collection-sharing), for CosmosDB because the SDK doesn't support it.

Comment: aaha! I thought adding the parameter would limit things but that is not the case then. I'll have a look at the ORM you're referring to. thanks!

Comment: We've decided not to investigate CosmosDB any further for this purpose at this moment. I'll be closing this question, therefore. Thanks to anybody who tried to help out!